# Deleting specific column in Cassandra from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

I was able to delete specific column with the RDD API with -

```
sc.cassandraTable("books_ks", "books")
  .deleteFromCassandra("books_ks", "books",SomeColumns("book_price"))
```

I am struggling to do this with the Dataframe API.

Can someone please share an example?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete via the DF API and it's unnatural via the RDD api. RDDs and DFs are immutable, meaning no modification. You can filter them to cut them down but this generates a new RDD / DF.

**Having said that** what you can do is filter out the rows that you wish to delete and then just build a C* client to carry out that deletion:

// imports for Spark and C* connection
    import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
    import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnectorConf

```
spark.setCassandraConf("Test Cluster", CassandraConnectorConf.ConnectionHostParam.option("localhost"))
val df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("keyspace" -> "books_ks", "table" -> "books")).load()
val dfToDelete = df.filter($"price" < 3).select($"price");
dfToDelete.show();


// import for C* client
import com.datastax.driver.core._

// build a C* client (part of the dependency of the scala driver)
val clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1");
val cluster  = clusterBuilder.build();
val session = cluster.connect();

// loop over everything that you filtered in the DF and delete specified row.
for(price <- dfToDelete.collect())
    session.execute("DELETE FROM books_ks.books WHERE price=" + price.get(0).toString);
```

*Few Warnings* This wont work well if you're trying to delete a large portion of rows. Using collect here means that this work will be done in Spark's driver program, aka SPOF & bottle-neck.

Better way to do this would be to go a) define a DF UDF to carry out the delete, benefit would be you get parallelization. Option b) to the RDD level and just the delete as you've shown above.

Moral of the story, just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should be done.